# React calling functions on unrendered objects

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a maze generator, with the following function being called from the constructor

```
  generateMaze(size){
    var maze = new Array(size);
    var oldrow = new Array(size);

    for(var i = 0; i < size; i++){
      oldrow[i] = <Cell group="0"></Cell>;
      if(i == 0){
        oldrow[i].setLeft(true);
      }else if(i == size - 1){
        oldrow[i].setRight(true);
      }
    }
    //snipped
}

Cell class:
class Cell extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      group : this.props.group,
      top : false,
      bottom : false,
      left : false,
      right : false
    };
  }
  group(){return this.state.group;}
  right(){return this.state.right;}
  left(){return this.state.left;}
  bottom(){return this.state.bottom;}
  top(){return this.state.top;}
  setLeft(value){
    this.setState({left : value});
  }
}
```

This resulted in TypeError: oldrow[i].setLeft is not a function
How can I solve this??

Comment: oldrow[i] = <Cell group="0"></Cell>; This should be wrong. jsx cannot be written like this as an assignment

Comment: @stack26 How should object creation be done for assignment?

Comment: @stack26 yes it can

Comment: Colin, just because you're making a variable a react element, doesn't mean you can call class methods like that. furthermore your `Cell` component does not have a `render` method so its invalid to begin with. you might want to look at a basic react tutorial to get started

Comment: Can i have an example for that . If you have any on jsfiddle . I never tried that.

Comment: @ColinSergi'18 `<Cell group="0"></Cell>` is not an instance of `Cell` class. It is an element.

Comment: @azium I have a render method that I snippeted out. Do you want to see it?

Comment: @ColinSergi'18 Have a read https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thank you. How would I convert a instance of a cell class into a child for purposes of rendering?

Comment: @stack26 https://codesandbox.io/s/95yw8vpny

Comment: @ColinSergi'18 It is not even clear what you want to achieve in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because your mixing things up.

You should first generate the maze (using arrays and objects and whatever you need).

Then you should pass the generated maze into a component that is going to interpret the maze and render the cells and all that stuff.